# what is a dead executor in spark(Pyspark)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am running a pyspark job where i noticed that there are dead executors, but the job finally succeeded. 

What is the impact of this when an executor is dead. 

What happens when executor, after completing the task, looses its connection and kills itself. Does the task is again initiated by getting new executor resulting in two time execution of the same task ?

Please help me to understand this.

Answer (score -1):

For starters I think just taking Wikipedia's spark page should be enough:

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark

Basically spark does the data processing in a fault-tolerant manner, which basically means, that some approaches to evaluate your dataframe might fail, some might succeed, and there's nothing bad about it. After failure it should just self-improve. Unless there's too many failures, and it fails whole job.

Spark knows intelligently how to process the data, yet sometimes you can (or have to in case of too many failures) help it by more efficient manual configuration like e.g. setting spark context with proper parameters, or smarter query organisation (rethink joins, broadcasting, maybe breaking down bigger tables into smaller chunks).

From my experience- the better configured job = less failures, and faster processing. It sometimes takes a lot of time to understand how to make your processing more efficient, yet you should aim for less failures and faster processing as the 2 indicators of better spark job.

Hope this helps

Comment: The page linked doesn't include the word "dead" at all.

Comment: @JoeLalgee have you read the whole response? It seems to me you're trying to make regex-based validation of my answer, instead of sense-based. Please elaborate why you think it's a problem?

Comment: This isn't a rant, it's just a bit long to provide the requested elaboration. Your answer does start by saying the wiki page should be enough. It's a fairly long wiki page which is clearly much broader than the subject of dead executors. I searched for the word "dead" to skip to the relevant part, and it turned out there is no relevant part as far as dead executors are concerned. So I'm not sure why I have been recommended to read this long article which doesn't attend to the question at all. I did read your answer in full, and it doesn't say what a dead executor is either.

Comment: So dead = failed i.e. language is designed in a way that it tolerates dead executors. It's provided by the quality called fault-tolerance (which is inherently spark thing). You can mitigate failing=dying, and you should aim to do that, however it's not an definite disadvantage, that your job has *some* failed=dead executors.

Comment: Let me know, if this address your concern - a bit broad alternatives in spark world - dead = failed

Comment: Thanks that helps